# action 'NAVIGATE' error when trying to navigate to nested navigator in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

I've just finished working on some authentication on my app where a user sign's in and when they click the sign in button, I also want them to navigate to a HomeScreen which is nested in a different Navigator.

I followed the React Navigation docs and thought I nested the screens and navigation routes correctly but the error I'm getting back is:

[image]

My SignUserIn function is working correctly as I get a 'success' message and Token in the console. So thinking I have an issue to do with my navigators?

When Sign In is pressed, I try to navigate to my Drawer navigator function name which is 'Root' and then 'Home' screen which is passed in as a param.

This is my App.js file:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useReducer,
  useMemo,
  useContext,
} from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import AppContext from './AuthContext';
import StateContext from './StateContext';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
import ttlock from './Assets/ttlock.png';
import {
  Pressable,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  Keyboard,
  Image,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  Platform,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer, DrawerActions} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import KeyboardAvoidingView from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/Keyboard/KeyboardAvoidingView';
import {navigationRef} from './RootNavigation';
import ResetPasswordScreen from './Screens/ResetPasswordScreen';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
  DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const AccountStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null);

  const AuthContext = AppContext;

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (prevState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            userToken: action.token,
            isLoading: false,
          };
        case 'SIGN_IN':
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: false,
            userToken: action.token,
          };
        case 'SIGN_OUT':
          // PushNotification.abandonPermissions();
          return {
            ...prevState,
            isSignout: true,
            userToken: null,
          };
      }
    },
    {
      isLoading: true,
      isSignout: false,
      userToken: null,
      surveys: [],
    },
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let userToken;

      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      } catch (e) {
        // Restoring token failed
      }

      dispatch({type: 'RESTORE_TOKEN', token: userToken});
    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);

  const authContext = useMemo(
    () => ({
      signIn: async data => {
        dispatch({type: 'SIGN_IN', token: data});
      },
      signOut: async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
        dispatch({type: 'SIGN_OUT'});
      },
      getSurveys: async () => {
        return state.surveys;
      },
    }),
    [],
  );

  function SignInScreen({navigation}) {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [device, setDevice] = useState('');
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
    const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState(null);
    const [surveys, setSurveys] = useState([]);

    const {signIn} = useContext(AuthContext);

    function signUserIn() {
      axios
        .post('https://app.doorbelldelivery.co.uk/api/login', {
          email: username,
          password: password,
          device_name: device,
        })
        .then(response => {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('token', 'Bearer ' + response.data);
          setUserToken(response.data);
          signIn(response.data);
          console.log('Token: ', response.data);
          console.log('success');
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Error: ', error.response);
          setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
        });
    }

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={styles.createContainer}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.topText}>Welcome Back</Text>
            <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>Email</Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Email"
              style={styles.inputBar}
              value={username}
              onChangeText={setUsername}
            />
            <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>Password</Text>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Password"
              value={password}
              onChangeText={setPassword}
              secureTextEntry
              style={styles.inputBar}
            />
            <Pressable
              style={styles.regBtn}
              onPress={() => {
                signUserIn();
                navigation.navigate('Root', {screen: 'Home'});
              }}>
              <Text style={styles.noAccountText}>Sign In</Text>
            </Pressable>

            <View />
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }

  function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
    const toggleUnlock = () => {};
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.subContainer}>
          <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
            <Text>Menu</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Text style={styles.titleText}>Door Lock 1</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <Button title="Open drawer" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
          <Image source={ttlock} style={styles.mainLogo} />
          <Pressable onPress={toggleUnlock} style={styles.unlockBtn}>
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>Unlock</Text>
          </Pressable>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }

  function GatewayScreen({navigation}) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Gateway Screen</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
    return (
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Close drawer"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.closeDrawer()}
        />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Toggle drawer"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );
  }

  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

  function Root() {
    return (
      <Drawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={GatewayScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      <StateContext.Provider value={state}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          {state.userToken == null ? (
            <AccountStack.Navigator>
              <AccountStack.Screen
                name="SignIn"
                options={{
                  title: 'Sign In',
                  headerShown: false,
                  animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push',
                }}
                component={SignInScreen}
                // component={HomeScreen}
              />
              <AccountStack.Screen
                name="ResetPassword"
                component={ResetPasswordScreen}
              />
            </AccountStack.Navigator>
          ) : (
            <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={Root} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          )}
        </NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar animated={true} backgroundColor="black" />
      </StateContext.Provider>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Many thanks in advance if anyone can point out where I'm going wrong!

Comment: you are not rendering the stack navigator at all , because of the turnery statement . I would recommend to create the "root" navigator and then use initial prop to handle routs

Comment: Take a look at the repo of [Bithoven on Github](https://github.com/bithoven-dev/ReactNavigationAuthenticationFlowsWithHooks/blob/master/src/App.js) to get familiar with the root navigator pattern :-)